# Canvas, how to set line dash of line?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just want to draw a dashed line by canvas with lineDash is [1,1]. I found the function `setLineDash`, in theory, that can do it. But I cannot make it work and cannot figure out how the function work. 
AFAIK, `setLineDash` function takes an argument that is an array. For example, `setLineDash([1,1])` should set the dash length to `1` and the space length to `1` too. But, it does not. It just draws a solid line. 
 
 Please take a look at the snippet below.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 300
canvas.height = 300

ctx.lineWidth = 3
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'

drawLine([1, 1], 25)
drawLine([2, 2], 50)
drawLine([3, 3], 75)
drawLine([4, 4], 100)
drawLine([5, 5], 125)
drawLine([6, 6], 150)
drawLine([7, 7], 175)
drawLine([8, 8], 200)
drawLine([9, 9], 225)

function drawLine(lineDash, y) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.setLineDash(lineDash)
  ctx.moveTo(200, y)
  ctx.lineTo(100, y)
  ctx.closePath()
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the culprit is the order of `ctx.closePath()` and `ctx.stroke()`. I called `ctx.stroke()` after closing the path so it makes the result go wrong.
Re-order the function call and it works as expected.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 300
canvas.height = 300

ctx.lineWidth = 3
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'

drawLine([1, 1], 25)
drawLine([2, 2], 50)
drawLine([3, 3], 75)
drawLine([4, 4], 100)
drawLine([5, 5], 125)
drawLine([6, 6], 150)
drawLine([7, 7], 175)
drawLine([8, 8], 200)
drawLine([9, 9], 225)

function drawLine(lineDash, y) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.setLineDash(lineDash)
  ctx.moveTo(200, y)
  ctx.lineTo(100, y)
  ctx.stroke()
  ctx.closePath()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setLineDash([1, 1]);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='350px' height='300px'></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain a bit about how your solution work?

Comment: I run your code two times and check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash#Basic_example. after that I found docs code was running every time. but your code was not.so i start  remove lines from your code and rearrange it same like docs and its work .then i post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the right answer and posted it below

Comment: @Duannx Great :)